# How to find out salary for faculty positions in private universities?

Tags: job-search, salary

Public university salary information is usually available online.  What about private universities?  Can average salary by field and rank be found at least?

Context: US/North America, mathematics

Comment: Some aggregate information may be available from the US department of education. But individual salaries at private universities is, I assume, not generally available. The reason it is available (in some places) for public universities is that faculty are considered "public employees", so the public has a right to know, at least in general terms. (Not everywhere, I think). There is, however, a law that requires universities to divulge their highness paid employees. This is usually a coach or medical or legal faculty, however. Occasionally the college president. Few mathematician, though.

Comment: https://data.chronicle.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the US and mathematics in particular, [the American Mathematical Society conducts annual salary surveys](http://www.ams.org/profession/data/annual-survey/salaries), broken down by various categories: public/private, highest degree offered in the department, rank, etc.  For example, in 2017-2018, at "large" private PhD-granting mathematics departments, the mean salary for new hire assistant professors was $94,675.

Answer (score 2):

It's far from perfect, but you could try looking at AAUP's [Faculty Compensation Survey](https://www.insidehighered.com/aaup-compensation-survey). This won't allow you to search by field, but it will show you average salaries by rank for each institution.

Comment: https://data.chronicle.com